# "Build" Classic ASP with TFS 2010

Tags: asp-classic

I'm using TFS 2010 for source control and for continuous integration (among other things). I've got a Classic ASP application that I maintain that I'd like to incorporate in a continuous integration build; however, I must supply a "Item to Build" in the build definition. Since Classic ASP doesn't have a solution or project associated with it, what are some ways I can still use a TFS 2010 Team Build, without having to mess with the "Items to Build"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that I determined my solution to be creating a solution and the .asp pages to the project to get TFS to move the files out, then use the modified deploy process to exclude the bin directory (since it's essentially empty).

Comment: Just a note on this, you can hand edit the .csproj or .vbproj file to include all .asp files rather than hand-picking. Not the use case for everyone, but there are some cases where this comes in handy.